# Trying to clone down a git repo that is large

Tags: git, github

When I clone down a large git repository from github (4.5gb) it says that I have changes in my working copy. How can that be, when I haven't touched it? Its happening on 4 files.

Im using Atlassian SourceTree GIT GUI on windows. I dont get any errors when cloning it down. git status only says changes not staged for commit.

Ive tried this twice now, with the same results.

Comment: what are these files? and what does their diff say?

Comment: its weird, some functions, lines have been removed that I dont recognise. One file just has first 500 files removed at the beginning. The point is, im just cloning whats on git, and its doesnt match up. When I try to check out, stash or even commit the files it wont let me.

Comment: also it will not let me stage the working copy changes